# Eclemma fails to install in Eclipse Mars 4.5.2

Tags: eclemma

Error shown while installing it from Eclipse MarketPlace.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: EclEmma Java Code Coverage 2.3.3.201602231923 (com.mountainminds.eclemma.feature.feature.group 2.3.3.201602231923)
  Missing requirement: EclEmma Java Code Coverage 2.3.3.201602231923 (com.mountainminds.eclemma.feature.feature.group 2.3.3.201602231923) requires 'org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.5.0' but it could not be found

Also tried manual installation of putting the plugins from zip file  to eclipse plugin folder, but eclemma icon is not visible in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

EclEmma is a tool for Java Code Coverage and so requires Eclipse Java development tools (JDT). So I'm guessing that they are not presented in your Eclipse installation. Try Mars 4.5.2 package "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers".

Answer (score 0):

For manual installation please download [the latest EclEmma release](https://www.eclemma.org/download.html).

Unzip the archive into dropins folder of your Eclipse installation and restart Eclipse:

```
    your eclipse installation location /eclipse/dropins/eclemma-x.y.z/
```